# Vundle error: Name collision for Plugin spf13/vim-colors

Tags: vim, vi

I tried the spf13 for my vim, but got an error just like below.

```
Vundle error: Name collision for Plugin spf13/vim-colors. Plugin spf13/vim-colors previously used the name "vim-colors". Skipping Plugin spf13/vim-colors.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I welcome to SO. I would try AskUbuntu or one of our linux subsites.

Comment: `spf13` is just a collection of `vim-plugins`. check your `.vimrc` you must have added the package `vim-colors` earlier. Or else put it on `github` you can get a better  solution

Comment: You can solve this problem by dropping spf13 as soon as possible and taking control of *your* config.

Answer (score 0):

you must find the spf13/vim-colors in .vimrc.bundles and

comment the line :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF4uI.png